# Making only certain cells in a gridview column linkbuttons

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview which pulls data from a database:

[image]

I wan't to make the content within task a linkbutton that can be clicked to show a popup with additional informatiom.

When I make the column linkbuttons it is also making Total: and Subtotal: a link button:
[image]

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task" ItemStyle-Width="20%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="taskLinkButton" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Eval("Task")%>'>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

How do I prevent these specific rows from being link buttons?

Comment: Are you returning the Subtotal and total rows as part of your dataset?

Comment: Yes everything except the very top row is from one query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit dirty but this should do the trick:

So i coulnt get to call Databinder.Eval inside <% %>, I'm not sure if it's actually possible, so I went with a different solution. The following worked for me (and its even shorter than last version):

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton Text='<%# Eval("task") %>' Visible='<%# Eval("incidentN") != null %>' runat="server" />
            <asp:Literal Text='<%# Eval("task") %>' Visible='<%# Eval("incidentN") == null %>' runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I think I understand what you are doing. DataBinder.Eval('ID') is causing an error saying: 'No overloaded methid 'Eval' takes 1 arguments' Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah sorry, i fixed my answer. You have to switch ID with the column name from your Incident# by the way, i just put ID cause you didnt put the rest of the column names.

Comment: I am getting: The name 'Container' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Let me fire up Visual Studio and give it a try :)

Comment: @DavidTunnell Check out my edit, this should work for you as well, you just gotta update column names etc. If your query doesnt return null, then just use String.IsNullOrEmpty to check if your first column has value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PlaceHolder with conditional visibility

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="Ok" runat="server" Visible='<%# (Eval("LoadStatus").ToString()=="false"?true:false) %>'><%----%>
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("Task")%>' runat="server" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="Ko" runat="server" Visible='<%# (Eval("LoadStatus").ToString()=="false"?false:true) %>'><%----%>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="taskLinkButton" runat="server"
                    Text='<%# Eval("Task")%>'>
                </asp:LinkButton>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```